# Perl Multithreading: ''forks'' vs ''threads'' in cross platforms scripts

Tags: perl

I'm trying to develop a software featuring multithreading.
On Linux the script works fine, the module i've used is ''forks''.
In other words, no problem of shared handlers between threads while querying db and stuff like that.
Once i've been trying to run the script on windows (Strawberry Perl), when i try to cpan install forks it says that ''forks module'' is not supported for the current version of my OS (64bit).
Moving over, i decided to use ''threads'' instead, but i gained the following error, almost certainly linked with shared handlers between threads.

''
Thread 1 terminated abnormally: DBD::SQLite::db prepare failed: handle 2 is owned by thread d97fe8 not current thread 3a01058 (handles can't be shared between threads and your driver may need a CLONE method added) at file.pl line 180,  line 1.
''

How to fix the aforementioned problem and make the script runnable on windows Strawberry Perl?

Comment: Seems you'll need to write the handling of your DB yourself using `fork` instead of threads, since the `forks` module works. The DB told you that you can't share a handle between threads, so you'll need to use processes to solve that.

Comment: Why did you use the _forks_ module, and not write your own stuff with the built-in `fork`? The docs of _forks_ says it's a drop-in replacement for when you already have _threads_, but don't want them anymore. [But it does not run on Windows, period](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=forks+0.36). There is no way to fix that. And _threads_ are just broken. You'll need to rebuild your own implementation using proper `fork`ing. How did you come up with the _forks_ module? I have been doing Perl for over 10 years and I had never heard of it before now.

Comment: It's a relatively new thing, triggered from 'threads are discouraged'. IMO there's not much in the way of good reasons to use it.

Comment: @simbabque, Sobrique  -- huh?  What precisely is wrong with `forks`?  It's there so that one can use the threads interface, what is nice and useful (for instance with pools etc), but without actual, heavy, threads.  Why not?  Now, on Windows ... _that's_ different.

Answer (score 3):

In general [each thread or process needs to have its own handle to the database](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Threads-and-Thread-Safety). Create a new handle after each `fork` or within each `threads::create`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks everybody for the prompt answer and the very good suggestions.
That's my solution.
Apparently, it seems there's no need to create a new db handler for each thread, just connect to the database each and every time you create a new thread.
So, if you're using ''threads'', i think it should be enough to include the following line within the ''threads->create'' method to make it runnable:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:SQLite:db_name.dbl" ) || die "Cannot connect: $DBI::errstr";
```

As you can see, the handler is static but it's not literally ''shared'' between 
threads, as it is created each and every time you connect to the db, so each and every time you run a new thread!

Please, don't ask me why the original script works fine in Linux using ''forks''  and without this trick...it seems that with ''forks'' you don't need to care about shared handlers.

Thanks again